# Cocoapods pod install gives undefined method inherit

Tags: cocoapods

I am getting this wierd error. If I look at the cocoapod specs, this seems like a valid syntax. What am I doing wrong.?

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined method `inherit!' for #<Pod::Podfile:0x007fad141d1050>. Updating CocoaPods might fix the issue.

 #  from /Users/Downloads/EarlGrey-master/Demo/EarlGreyExample/Podfile:28
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  target TEST_TARGET do
 >    inherit! :search_paths
 #    pod 'EarlGrey'
```

Comment: which cocoapods verison do you use?

Answer (score 5):

**Open your Podfile and Remove Project_Tests block.**

for example,

**Following Gives Error :**

```
use_frameworks!

target 'MyPodProject_Example' do
  pod 'MyPodProject', :path => '../'

  target 'MyPodProject_Tests' do
    inherit! :search_paths


  end
end
```

**Successful:**

```
use_frameworks!

target 'MyPodProject_Example' do

  pod 'MyPodProject', :path => '../'

end
```

Then do **pod update** (in terminal). This will create the **.xcworkspace**

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the latest version of Cocoapods installed.
As mentioned by Zoidberg, you need to have at least version 1.0 (which is now stable) in order to support 'inherit'.

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

With this your `pod install` should not give you any errors.

Answer (score 1):

I face a similar problem, here is what worked for me

```
sudo gem install cocoapods --pre
```

this will basically install the 1.0.0.beta.6 version of cocoapods which has 'inherit'